# How do I flush out the DNS resolver cache?

Tags: dns, cache

On Microsoft Windows OS, at the command prompt, I issue the command ipconfig /flushdns to flush out the DNS resolver cache.

On Ubuntu 12.10, what is the corresponding command?

Answer (score 4):

You do that by restarting `nscd`

To install nscd Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install nscd
```

To flush DNS Cache do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

Comment: Synaptic has this in the description: "A daemon which handles passwd, group and host lookups 
for running programs and caches the results for the next
query. You should install this package only if you use
**slow services** like LDAP, NIS or NIS+." So is that why it isn't installed by default? (I don't have it installed.)

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't include nscd in the default installation.  I really don't know why, but I guess its because it doesn't cache dns names by default.